# Looping through bs4.element.tag

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a rss feed for a news site and pull out the date published, title, description, and link to the actual article. So far with these lines of code:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(f, 'lxml')
    all_item_tags = soup.find_all('item')
    first = all_item_tags[0]
    second = all_item_tags[1]
    print(first.contents[9].contents[0], first.contents[1].contents[0], first.contents[4], first.contents[5].contents[0])
    print(second.contents[9].contents[0], second.contents[1].contents[0], second.contents[4], second.contents[5].contents[0])
```

I get that info but i'm having trouble figuring out how to loop it to grab all the indices of `all_item_tags` and then the `.contents[].contents[]` of those indices without having to write `first` `second` `third` etc.

Edit: The contents of `text.txt` - http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/index.rss

Comment: can you provide text.txt?

Comment: How about `for item_tag in all_item_tags` ?

Comment: it worked ty!!! item_tag in all_item_tags

Comment: @Lil_Scuba Please accept the community wiki answer posted below (which just reiterates the comment that solved your problem). This way, it is clear that the question no longer needs addressing.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments section:

> How about `for item_tag in all_item_tags`? – [t.m.adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7811673/t-m-adam)

Answer (score 0):

The feed is already provided as an RSS document. Instead of using beautifulsoup to parse it, save yourself the hassle of **scraping** the page and use [feedparser](https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser) instead. It parses RSS and Atom and does a great deal to normalize content for you. It's been a lifesaver while building a corpus of news articles while learning natural language processing.

Install feedparser

```sh
pip install feedparser
```

Parse the feed

```py
import feedparser

dailymail = feedparser.parse('http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/index.rss')
for entry in dailymail.feed.entries:
  title = item.get('title', 'No title')
  description = item.get('summary', 'No descrition.')
```